# dyld: Symbol not found: _SCNSceneExportPresentationTree

Tags: ios, iphone, ios11, xcode9, arkit

When I tried to run my app with Xcode 9 on iPhone 5s which is updated with iOS 11, App gets crashed on the launch screen. The log printed is:

**dyld: Symbol not found: _SCNSceneExportPresentationTree**

**Referenced from: /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib**

**Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/SceneKit.framework/SceneKit
 in /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib**

From the log, it seems that it is because of some new ARKit changes with Xcode, but my app does not use any of the ARKit related frameworks.

Can anyone help here?

Comment: Do you have any Cocoapods installed in your project ?

Comment: @TahaAmini yes i have.

Comment: Try doing a pod install to reset the configurations of your pods, that might solve your issue.

Comment: @TahaAmini, What do you mean by reset configurations here?